# PostgreSQL CREATE USER with password using windows password policy

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm looking for a way to create a user with password for PostgreSQL >= 8.4 using SQL statement, but the password must match the windows password policy.

At MSSQL I can create a `LOGIN` and set `CHECK_POLICY=ON`

```
CREATE LOGIN [xy] WITH PASSWORD='pass', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[mydb], CHECK_POLICY=ON
```

and later create the user for this login.

Is there something similar for PostgreSQL? I have to support all versions beginning at 8.4.

Thank you

Comment: You will want SSPI authentication mode, where PostgreSQL defers user authentication to Windows.

Comment: @CraigRinger Does that mean, that I have to create a windows user account and use it to authenticate to postgres?

Comment: If you wish to enforce Windows's password policy, yes. PostgreSQL has its own password policy options you can use instead, but it'll be separate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/passwordcheck.html
Think this works since Version 9.0.

Comment: Version 8.4 is end-of-life from July this year. Not sure how much effort you'll want to go to. http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: @RichardHuxton sure, but the head developer decided to support 8.4 as well ;)